# PHP socket_write failure only returns error on next call

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, arduino, iot

I am trying to send data by PHP sockets, the client is an Arduino device, it receives the data OK when I send it multiple times, but if I reset the client (Arduino device), it reboots in a few seconds, it says it connected to the PHP socket, then when I want to send data again by `socket_send()` it fails silently, the PHP `socket_send()` is not returning an error on first actual error, only the second time I try (and fail), only then it returns error ("zero bytes sent"). When this error is received, I create another `socket_accept()` and successfully send the message.

What could cause this ? I want it to properly detect a lost connection so I can resend data if needed.

It feels like it sends data to an old connection and only realizes it on second try, is that possible ?

Can this be fixed by `socket_select()` ? I have trouble understanding what that does.

Clarification: If client restarts and connects again, then sending data to it returns `int`, then `false`, `false`, `false` (unless I unset the `$accept` and I do a  `socket_accept()` again). If client remains offline, then the sending always returns `int`, `int`, `int`.
`int` being the size of the string sent.

```php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");

// reuse any existing open port to avoid error
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

    
do{

    if(!isset($accept)){
        echo "\nwaiting for clients";
        $accept = @socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection");
        echo "\nclient connected";
    }
    
    // memcached will return a message here like: "my message\r\n"
    $message_to_send = $memcached->get('my_socket_message');
    
    if($message_to_send!=''){

        echo "\nsending: ".$message_to_send;
    
        $total_data_sent = @socket_send($accept, $message_to_send, strlen($message_to_send), MSG_EOR);
    
        // if data was not send (sent to an old connection ?!)...
        // then clear $accept, so a new connection is accepted
        // and keep the my_socket_message variable, so message is sent again

        if($total_data_sent === false){
            echo "\nSEND FAILED, will retry message: ".$message_to_send;
            unset($accept);
        } else {
            $memcached->delete('my_socket_message');
        }
    
    }
    
} while (true);
```

Comment: When you say "it fails silently" what is the exact result of `@socket_send(` (var_dump please)? [socket_select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) returns the number of sockets which changed status, so `$checkExcept = [$accept];` and `socket_select(null, null, $checkExcept);` should return 1 on error.

Comment: First time I try to send and client is disconnected it returns `int(32)` (string size) and only when I call it again, it returns `bool(false)`. Since client would be fully offline, there is no way this is a client side problem, no ?

Comment: If client restarts and connects again, then sending data to it returns `int`, then `false`, `false`, `false` (unless I unset the `$accept` and I do a  `socket_accept()` again). If client remains offline, then the sending always returns `int`, `int`, `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experimented a bit and was able to reproduce the issue. Here is my solution for it (maybe not the best way, but works):

```
@socket_send($accept, $message_to_send, strlen($message_to_send), MSG_EOR);
$dataSent = @socket_write($accept, '', 0);

    if ($dataSent === false) {
        unset($accept);
        // ...
```

## edit

I came up with a more neat solution. We just do what the `socket_send` function is supposed to do. Return `false` or `int` number of received bytes.

On the receiving end you just decode the message (`$data`) and send back the `strlen` of `$data['payload']`. The client can verify it has received all data like this too. To do so just compare `strlen` of `$data['payload']` with `$data['length']`. If you really get paranoid you can implement some checksum aswell.

Code for Server use `send` instead of `socket_send`:

```
function send($client, $message) {
    $messageLength = strlen($message);

    $data = [
        'length' => $messageLength,
        'payload' => $message
    ];
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);

    try {
        @socket_send($client, $jsonData, strlen($jsonData), MSG_EOR);
        $response = @socket_read($client, 1024);

        if (intval($response) !== $messageLength) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $response;
}
```

Even though this works, I thought TCP does exactly that - ensure the data has been received. Maybe we are still missing something here.

Comment: This one basically does another send, right ? That could be a solution, to send some dummy data before real data in order to trigger the error. It could work but it feels like we are doing something wrong. I will also post the solution I ended up using. Thanks.

Comment: @adrianTNT I added another approach to this. May I ask in what language your client is written? If its php, I can provide some propper client code aswell.

Comment: It is an ESP32 wifi board, coding in Arduino language, which is a `C/C++` language. I found it works well waiting for an "ok" reply/confirmation, I will probably check number of bytes returned too, as you said in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using and it seems to work nicely.
It waits for a reply/confirmation from client, if no confirmation received, `message_to_send` is preserved, connection is cleared, on next loop it reconnects and retries to send the existent `message_to_send`.

```
$total_data_sent = @socket_send($accept, $message_to_send, strlen($message_to_send), MSG_EOR);

// set a timeout for waiting a reply, in this case 500 milliseconds
socket_set_option($accept, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>0, "usec"=>500000));

// read a reply, which should be "ok" (text sent by client)
$reply = socket_read($accept, 1024);

// if reply was not "ok", then unset the connection and will reconnect on next loop
if($reply != "ok"){
    unset($accept);
}

// if reply was "ok", then clear this message as it was successfuly sent
if($reply == "ok"){
    unset($message_to_send);
}
```